# Synchronously load a module whose name is determined at runtime in ES6

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

With CommonJS, `require` calls are synchronous, one can easily load a module dynamically like this:

```
require('./' + localModulePath);
```

ES6 introduces `System.import` which returns a Promise, and the standard `import` seems to not allow names that are determined at runtime. Is this a feature of CommonJS that is missing with ES6 modules or am I missing something?

Comment: In `import * from "string"`, wouldn't `"string"` be dynamic?

Comment: @elclanrs according to the spec it has to be a string literal.

Comment: I don't understand why it's a problem that `System.import()` returns a promise.

Comment: @Pointy I don't mind that it returns a promise, but it seems that it there isn't the option to do something that CJS already does. This seems like a compromise.

Comment: FYI, I don't think `System.import` is in latest ES6 draft anymore — people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a feature of CommonJS that is missing with ES6 modules or am I missing something?

I don't think so. The fact that the module loading process is asynchronous allows you to use the same way in different environments. E.g. in a browser it wouldn't be possible to load the module synchronously, or at least we want to avoid it because synchronously fetching resources in JS is bad.

However, the `import` syntax gives you the impression of synchronous loading. It was a deliberate decision to make the statement statically analyzable so that environments can load all the dependencies before they excute the script, in which ever way they want.

Comment: Ah, it's a bug in CommonJS that ES6 is missing :-)

Comment: The use case is if I have a bunch of modules in memory already, but which module gets loaded depends on runtime, and I don't want to wait on the next tick because the modules are already in memory and there is synchronous code immediately after the module is loaded. Perhaps it's an edge case nobody cares about because yolo async all the things.